# The fsolve function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of numbers for one of the variables in an fsolve equation so when I run matlab I am hoping to get back a matrix but instead get a scalar. I even tried a for loop but this gave me an error about size so that is not the solution. I am including the code to get some feedback as to what i am doing wrong.

```
z=0.1;
bubba =[1 1.5 2];
bubba = bubba';

 joe = 0:0.1:1.5;
 joe = repmat(joe,3,1);
 bubba = repmat(bubba,1,length(joe));
 for x=1:1:16
 eqn0 = @(psi0) (joe.-bubba.*(sqrt((psi0+z))));
 result0(x) = fsolve(eqn0,0.1,options);

 end
```

note I need the joe variable later for plotting so I clipped that part of the code.

Comment: Which variable in your equation is a matrix? I see `z=0.1;`, and the local variable `psi0`. As you go around the loop, nothing inside the loop is changing (nothing depends on `i`). So what do you expect to happen? As an aside, please don't use `i` as a variable name - it likes it role as `sqrt(-1)` and when you overwrite that, who knows what side effects it has on other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your earlier comments, let me take a shot at a solution... still not sure this is what you want:

```
bubba =[1 1.5 2];
joe = 0:0.1:1.5;

for xi = 1:numel(joe)
  for xj = 1:numel(bubba)
    eqn0 = @(psi0) (joe(xi).-bubba(xj).*(sqrt((psi0+z))));
    result(xi,xj) = fsolve(eqn0,0.1,options);
  end
end
```

It is pedestrian; but is it what you want? I can't access matlab right now, otherwise I might come up with something more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment:

`psi0` is the independent variable in your solver. You set the dimension of it to [1 1] when you use a scalar as the second argument of `fsolve(eqn0, 0.1, options);` - this tells Matlab to optimize the scalar `psi0`, starting at a value of `0.1`. The result will be a scalar - the value that minimizes the function

```
0.1 * sqrt(psi0 + 0.1)
```

since you had set z=0.1

You should get a value of -0.1 returned for every iteration of your loop, since you never changed anything.  There is not enough information right now to figure out which factor you would like to be a matrix - especially since your expression for `eqn0` involves a matrix multiplication, it's hard to know what you expect the dimensionality of the result to be.

I hope that you will use this initial answer as a springboard to modify your question so it can be answered properly!?

Comment: I apologize but when I copied my code in it looks like part of the equation was dropped and will take care of fixing the i problem. So the correct part of the equation is : eqn0 = @(psi0) (joe.-bubba.*(sqrt((psi0+z))));
result0(x) = fsolve(eqn0,0.1,options);  modified now to replace i with x

Comment: Please "edit" your question with this information. You still have `x0` (initial guess) as a scalar... `(0.1)`. Intentional?

Comment: Yeah I am wanting to do the fsolve on each point in the matrix one at a time.

Comment: Unless z is a function of x, your loop still does nothing (or rather it does the same thing n times)

Comment: so if I wanted to then solve the individual scalar point of bubba how would I do it then?